# Filesystem: How to find block of file represented by inode?

Tags: filesystems, inode, superblock

I am writing a file system for my operating system and am doing research on existing file systems before I start designing my own.  I came across some slides about the System Five File System and am pretty confused on how blocks of files are found.

For example, if I wanted to find block 5 of the file represented by inode 12...how would I do this?

Can someone explain (at a high level) how to find a block of a file represented by an inode?

Comment: Are you asking how ufs does it, or how one (you) *might* do it?

Comment: For now, I'm asking about the ufs (not that it matters too much, but the unix V fs).

Comment: Read http://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/0131482092/samplechapter/mcdougall_ch15.pdf and if you still don't get it, read it again.

Comment: Use istat command from the sleuthkit package. The istat command prints the direct and indirect blocks used by the inode.

Answer (score 3):

Structures fetched from Ultrix 3.0 v7 of `restor` so variations can occur:

ftp://ftp.uvsq.fr/pub/tuhs/PDP-11/Distributions/dec/Ultrix-3.0/v7restor/include/sys/

The s5fs is rather archaic but ...:

Disk layout could be something like:

```
[B][S][Inode List][ Data Blocks ]
 |  |
 |  +-- Super Block
 +----- Boot Area
```

The *Super Block* holds data for the file system. The *Inode List* is an array of inodes holding data for files (including directories) and *pointers* to the data residing in the *Data Blocks*.

The *Inode List* is of fixed size.

Structure of the *Super Block* on disk:

```
struct  filsys {
    unsigned short s_isize;  /* size in blocks of i-list */
    daddr_t s_fsize;         /* size in blocks of entire volume */
    short   s_nfree;         /* number of addresses in s_free */
    daddr_t s_free[NICFREE]; /* free block list */
    short   s_ninode;        /* number of i-nodes in s_inode */
    ino_t   s_inode[NICINOD];/* free i-node list */
    char    s_flock;         /* lock during free list manipulation */
    char    s_ilock;         /* lock during i-list manipulation */
    char    s_fmod;          /* super block modified flag */
    char    s_ronly;         /* mounted read-only flag */
    time_t  s_time;          /* last super block update */
    daddr_t s_tfree;         /* total free blocks*/
    ino_t   s_tinode;        /* total free inodes */
    short   s_m;             /* interleave factor */
    short   s_n;
    char    s_fname[6];      /* file system name */
    char    s_fpack[6];      /* file system pack name */
    long    s_unique;        /* saved unique number (sys unique) */
};
```

Structure of a *Inode* on disk:

```
struct dinode
{
    unsigned short  di_mode; /* mode and type of file */
    short   di_nlink;        /* number of links to file */
    short   di_uid;          /* owner's user id */
    short   di_gid;          /* access control file (was gid) */
    off_t   di_size;         /* number of bytes in file */
    char    di_addr[40];     /* disk block addresses */
    time_t  di_atime;        /* time last accessed */
    time_t  di_mtime;        /* time last modified */
    time_t  di_ctime;        /* time created */
};
```

`di_mode` would tell you if it is a regular file, directory, named pipe etc. and what permissions it holds.

You are specifically asking about the `di_addr`. This holds 13 three byte addresses, total of 39 bytes. The last byte is used by some systems as file creation mask for directories.

The `lib.c` file at root of the `restor` source, (see top),  holds functions for convert longs to and from 3-byte disk addresses.

The first 10 are direct pointers, 11-13 are indirect pointers.

As you request block number 5, that would be a direct pointer. Read it's value and read the data from that block.

Another ref: http://erdos.csie.ncnu.edu.tw/~ccyang/Os2/Slides/chapter9.ppt